# Unable to sign out on an ipad

Tags: support

As far as I can tell, the only way to sign out of this site is to hover over your name, an action which is impossible on an ipad. Everything else on the site works well on my ipad, it even renders the tex correctly. I was wondering if it would be possible to give an alternate sign out method.

Comment: I don't have an appropriate device to test—does clicking on the little triangle next to your name make the popup show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On an iPad2 in Safari, I lightly tap on my name on top to open the drop down which enables me to log out. (An extended tap would take you to a different page and if you press your finger it asks to open in new page, etc. This takes some time getting used to.)

Here's a [link](http://octidextro.us/2010/04/05/ipad-and-onmouseover/) [explaining](http://billhiggins.us/blog/2010/04/05/the-ipad-and-onmouseover/) [onmouseover](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) capability of ipad:

- If a link has no “on mouseover”
  actions (e.g. hovers), a tap follows
  to the link.
- If a link has an “onmouseover”
  action, a tap activates the
  onmouseover action and a double-tap
  follows the link.

Although technically it is classified as a "single tap" and a "double tap", most borwser apps are not calibrated to touchscreen sensitivity and taps in my experience. So a normal touch or tap causes mouseover preview to fire, but immediately follows the link. That is why I cautioned that the "light tap" takes a little time to get used to.

EDIT: If you're not accustomed to the "light tap" then zoom in and tap the inverted grey arrow left to your name and you'll see the logout button. 
[image]

Comment: Oh, yes: this sounds much more like the correct solution than my workaround. But you need to know this device in order to give that answer :)

Comment: Very good to know! I swear I hit my name a hundred times and that never came up before. BTW this works on original ipad as well.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** yayu gave an answer that seems much more to the point. In case this answer is still accepted when you read this please read his answer before you go for my workaround.

---

For the sake of having a quick answer: I don't know of another place where the logout link can be found, but you should be able to logout by clicking this link:

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/logout

or entering it manually (that's where the logout link in the popup frame goes to). You should then be able to log out by clicking on the logout button there. As I don't own an iPad, I can't test it, though.

---

**Added:**

This seems to work, and bookmarking that link (or copy-pasting it into your bio) should be a viable solution as long as there is no accessible direct link on the main page.

Comment: That worked great. Bookmarking that page is a good enough solution for me.

Comment: @Matt: Great! I added your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Clever solution to the problem!  My thoughts were not leading to an elegant solution.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks! ${}$